# Access text-input attributes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('.centering').click(function (e) {
    $(".thVal").replaceWith(function () {
        console.log(this);
        return this.value;
    });
    $('.editFields').hide();
});
```

This gives med the following output:

```
 <input class="thVal" width="2" type="text" modelbind="LicenseHolder_LegalPerson_Name" value="Test Oil AB">
5505094091(rad 256)
<input class="thVal" width="2" type="text" modelbind="LicenseHolder_LegalPerson.PrimaryAddress_StreetAddress" value="Testgatan 1">
5505094091
<input class="thVal" width="2" type="text" modelbind="LicenseHolder_LegalPerson_PrimaryAddress_ZipCode" value="50010">
5505094091(rad 256)
<input class="thVal" width="2" type="text" modelbind="x => x_LicenseHolder_LegalPerson_PrimaryAddress_HomeTown" value="Växjö Sverige">
5505094091(rad 256)
<input class="thVal" width="2" type="text" modelbind="" value="0730730037">
```

When I write `console.log(this.value)`, the values of the inputs are displayed. But I want to access the value of the modelbind-attribute, and when I write `console.log(this.modelbind)`, I just get undefined.

How can I access the value?

Comment: `console.log($(this).attr("modelbind"));`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value using [**.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

```
console.log($(this).attr("modelbind"))
```

And it will be better if you use [**data-attribute**](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/)